Can't compose_call with call function limited_reserve_transfer_assets - python substrate interface?
This question relates to building the call_params for the compose_call function. I have the params for the rest correct, but have trouble building the assets attribute params?
Here's a reference I followed:
https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-metadata-docs/statemint/polkadotxcm/#limited_reserve_transfer_assets
And here's the assets attribute I've created:
assets = {
    "V3": [
        {
            "fun": {
                "Fungible": "10000000000"
            },
            "id": {
                "Concrete": {
                    "interior": {
                        "X2": {
                            "col0": {
                                "PalletInstance": 50
                            },
                            "col1": {
                                "GeneralIndex": "1984"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "parents": 0
                }
            }
        }
    ],

}

It seems correct, but when i try to execute, I kept getting this error:
raise ValueError("Provided value is not a list")
ValueError: Provided value is not a list
What am I doing wrong?
